# MacOSX Lion: how to move a named window using CoreGraphics, without AppleScript?

Tags: cocoa, window, core-graphics, osx-lion, move

Using CoreGraphics in a cocoa objective-c program running under Lion, I'd like to move a named window that is owned by a different process. I know I can do this via an auxiliary AppleScript method via ASOC, but I want to perform this task entirely within cocoa using CoreGraphics (or at least entirely within C or objective-c), and without any AppleScript, at all.

I know how to locate a named window of a named process using the code below, but once I get the info for that window, I haven't been able to figure out how to move it (see the comment "What do I do here ... ?" within this code). Could someone point me to some docs or make a suggestion as to how I can proceed?

Thanks in advance.

```
+(boolean_t)moveWindow:(NSString*)windowName ofProcess:(NSString*)processName to:(CGPoint*)location {

    boolean_t result = false;

    if (windowName == nil || processName == nil || location == nil) {
        return (result);
    }

    CFArrayRef windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
    CFIndex   nWindows = CFArrayGetCount(windows);

    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < nWindows; i++) {
        CFDictionaryRef windict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windows, i);
        CFNumberRef winOwnerPidRef = CFDictionaryGetValue(windict, kCGWindowOwnerPID);
        if (winOwnerPidRef == nil) {
            continue;
        }
        pid_t winOwnerPid = 0;
        CFNumberGetValue(winOwnerPidRef, kCFNumberSInt32Type, (int*)&winOwnerPid);
        if (winOwnerPid < 1) {
            continue;
        }
        ProcessSerialNumber winOwnerPSN;
        GetProcessForPID(winOwnerPid, &winOwnerPSN);

        NSString* winOwner = nil;

        ProcessSerialNumber psn;
        psn.lowLongOfPSN  = kNoProcess;
        psn.highLongOfPSN = 0;

        while (winOwner == nil && GetNextProcess(&psn) == noErr) {

            if (psn.lowLongOfPSN  != winOwnerPSN.lowLongOfPSN ||
                psn.highLongOfPSN != winOwnerPSN.highLongOfPSN) {
                continue;
            }
            CFStringRef procName = NULL;
            if (CopyProcessName(&psn, &procName) == noErr) {
                winOwner = (NSString*) procName;
            }
            CFRelease(procName);
        }

        if (winOwner == nil || [winOwner compare:processName] != NSOrderedSame) {
            continue;
        }

        CFStringRef winNameRef = CFDictionaryGetValue(windict, kCGWindowName);
        NSString* winName = (NSString*) winNameRef;
        if (winName != nil && [winName compare:windowName] == NSOrderedSame) {
            // ********************************************** //
            // What do I do here in order to move the window? //
            // ********************************************** //
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return (result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the windows of other applications using Accessibility. Take a look at `AXUIElementCreateApplication()` and `AXUIElementSetAttributeValue()` with the attribute kAXPositionAttribute.

Note that Accessibility will need to be enabled (check "Enable access for assistive devices" in Universal Access Preferences) or your process will need to be trusted (see `AXMakeProcessTrusted()`)

Comment: Yours is indeed the solution, but I don't know how to flag it as such, except for clicking on the button that says that the post is useful to me, which I just noticed and I just did. I'm new here, so maybe I'm missing something else, as well. Also, I'm not allowed to vote up your post, also because I'm new here. Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Look for a white checkmark to the left of this answer, right below the up vote counter. Clicking that should turn it green and marks the question as the answer.